# Flask WTForms cannot save file to different directory

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm learning Flask with WTForms and i'm trying to upload a file to the server. The structure of my app is like:

```
| app
|- mod_users
   |- models.py
   |- forms.py
   | views.py
|- templates
|- static
| run.py
| config.py
```

In my views.py I have:

```
@mod.route('/post/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
  form = PostForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    filename = secure_filename(form.imageFile.data.filename)
    form.imageFile.data.save('/app/static/images/books/' + filename)
```

If I have ***form.imageFle.data.save(filename)*** then the app works and save the image to the same folder where "app" is located. But when I change it to the above I have the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/static/images/testupload/test.png'
```

My goal is to save the uploaded image to /app/static/images/testupload/

How do I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out the probem that the directory should be "app/static/images/testupload/" without the leading / in front.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you needed to take out the trailing '/'. For those using blueprints, you also have to declare the entire pathway.